# Unintuitive removeClass() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this flip plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/), see the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdJHH/).  The goal is to flip one box at a time, e.g. the second box clicked should `revertFlip()` the previous one.  During the animation I don't want the other boxes to be clickable.  I noted that the `removeClass()` is not working.

```
<div class='flippable'>I'm unflipped 1</div> 
...
<div class='flippable'>I'm unflipped 9</div>
```

```
$('.flippable:not(.reverted)').live('click',function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $prevFlip = $('.reverted'); 
        var $allBoxes = $('.flippable');      

        $this.flip(
        {
            direction: 'lr',
            color: '#82BD2E',
            content: 'now flipped',
            onBefore: function()
            { 
                $prevFlip.revertFlip();
                $prevFlip.removeClass('reverted'); 
            },
            onAnimation: function () 
            { 
                $allBoxes.preventDefault();
            },
            onEnd: function()
            { 
                $this.addClass('reverted');
            }
         })
    return false;
    });
```

I'll appreciate a lot your advise and suggestions.

Edit:
 
**Error Console Output:** `$allBoxes.preventDefault is not a function`

Comment: Just a side note, you don't have to prefix your variables with a $.  Typically this is done to resolve naming conflicts.

Comment: I like to prepend $ to jQ variables, for the others not, that's my convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this has something to do with `revertFlip()` calling `onBefore` and `onEnd`.  This is causing some weirdness with `addClass` and `removeClass`.  Check out my modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/7cysr/.

You'll see if you open up FireBug that `onBefore` and `onEnd` are called multiple times, with I *think* is having the following effect (I haven't exactly worked out what's going on):

1. The call to `onEnd` for the normal "flip" sets reverted class for the desired element.
2. The call to `onEnd` for the "revert flip" action sets the same element as above *again* when onEnd is called.

Here's a workaround.  I've taken out using `onBegin` and simplified `onEnd` since I'm not exactly sure what's going on with the `revertFlip()` call:

```
$(function() {
    var handlerEnabled = true;
    $('.flippable:not(.reverted)').live('click', function() {
        if (handlerEnabled) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $prevFlip = $('.reverted');
            var $allBoxes = $('.flippable');

            handlerEnabled = false;

            $prevFlip.revertFlip();
            $prevFlip.removeClass("reverted");
            $this.addClass("reverted");

            $this.flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                color: '#82BD2E',
                content: 'now flipped',
                onEnd: function() {
                    handlerEnabled = true;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
})
```

I'm using a boolean flag to enable and disable the event listener.  Try out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/bX9pb/.  It should work as you described in your OP (only flipping one over at a time).

Your original code (`$allBoxes.preventDefault()`) is invalid, because `$allBoxes` is a collection of elements.  `preventDefault` is a function on the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this script

```
var $prevFlip;
$('.flippable:not(.reverted)').live('click',function()     {         
    var $this = $(this);         
    var $allBoxes = $('.flippable');                
    $this.flip(         {             
        direction: 'lr',             
        color: '#82BD2E',             
        content: 'now flipped',             
        onBefore: function()             {           
            if($prevFlip){
                $prevFlip.revertFlip();                 
                $prevFlip.removeClass('reverted');              
            }
        },             
        onAnimation: function ()              {                  
            //$allBoxes.preventDefault();             
            //This is not a valid line
        },             
        onEnd: function()             {                  
            $this.addClass('reverted');      
            $prevFlip = $this;
        }          
    });    
    return false;     
});
```

This reverts only one previous item. This is not a complete solution. I think there are more problems to this. I'll post any further updates if I found them.

I think [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514870/unintuitive-removeclass-problem/4515761#4515774) got the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter `$this` out of `$allBoxes` by using the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

```
$allBoxes.not($this).revertFlip();
```