# ajax return showing nan

Tags: jquery, ajax

the problem im having is first of all
i have a page called ajax.php which with this url ajax.php?id=0001 returns

```
{"value":250,"price":"5"}
```

this is the jquery portion

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    //field variables

    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    var price = $("#pricing p.pps span").text();

    //onload display default data.
    $.get("ajax.php", { id: quantity }, function(data) { $("#pricing p.pps span").html(data.price); }, "json");



    //quantity select
    $("#quantity").change(
    function() 
    { 
        $.get("ajax.php", { id: quantity }, 
            function(data) 
            {
                total = parseInt(price) + parseInt(data.price);
                $("#pricing p.pps span").html(total);       
            }, "json");
    });

});
```

when the page loads the pricing span gets the value outputted. but when i select the quantity selection the pricing span gets a nan value. can anyone see why?

Comment: Are you extremely sure that the data you're getting back from `ajax.php` is always correct? Can you try alerting data.price in that `.change()` method?

Answer (score 2):

your `price` variable is evaluated before any ajax call is made. what is the value of `price` immediately after this line:

```
var price = $("#pricing p.pps span").text();
```

if its not a number then the `parseInt(price)` call will return `NaN`

you should set your `price` var in the callback of the first ajax get:

```
var price = 0;
$.get("ajax.php", { id: quantity }, function(data) { 
    $("#pricing p.pps span").html(data.price); 
    price = data.price;
}, "json");
```

Comment: I also need some advise. Can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514870/  I'll appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

There can be two issues with the code. First the `price` value from the `$("#pricing p.pps span").text()`  line may not be a number so `parseInt(price)` may return `NaN`.

Second the `data.price` coming from the ajax request may not be a valid number so again parseInt(data.price) may return `NaN`.

The nest way to solve this problem is to keep an alert statement like

```
alert("price: " + price + ", data.price: " + data.price)
```

before the line

```
total = parseInt(price) + parseInt(data.price);
```

The main problem is the `price` value is set before the first ajax call that means the price value is an empty string, I think. You have to update the first ajax call as

```
var price = 0;
$.get("ajax.php", { 
    id: quantity 
}, function(data) { 
    $("#pricing p.pps span").html(data.price); 
    price = parseInt(data.price)
}, "json");
```

Then you can use it as

```
total = price + parseInt(data.price);
```

Another thing to keep in mind is the [`radix`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) parameter when you work with `parstInt()` method. It is the number system to be used to parse the string like hexa, octa etc. If you miss this parameter parseInt can return unexpected results if the string starts with a `0` or `0x`. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is caused by this part: total = **parseInt(price)** + parseInt(data.price);

The "price" is undefined in the ajax callback function. You need to define it and give it a value.

Comment: price is defined, just in the outside scope. the ajax function will still have a reference to it.